# Views fields settings style settings no options avaible

Tags: 7, views

In views, after I choose 'Fields' as format, I want to add HTML to the title field. 
The way you would normally do this is is expand the "Style settings" fieldset, then check "Customize field HTML". Only on the Drupal site in question there is nothing that expands under the checked item. I checked permissions and flushed caches but other than that I don't know how I woul be able to look at this. Could this be a javascript issue? Also checked console for that, but no errors there.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found that it is caused by using jQuery 1.8, so with an older jQuery versions it should works just fine.

Comment: Fortunately, jQuery Update allows for a separate jQuery version on admin pages, so I was still able to have the version I needed for the public part of the site, while using your solution to fix the Views functionality.